# Nested foreach loops to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to rewrite this code to LINQ? I'm new to linq and it seems difficult to understand.

```
foreach (Employee employee in EmployeeList)
{
    Earnings earnings = new Earnings(employee.Name, employee.LastName, employee.Bank, employee.Account);
    if (!EarningsList.Contains(earnings))
    {
        EarningsList.Add(earnings);
    }
    foreach (DaysData item in ProductList)
    {
        foreach (Product product in item.Products)
        {
            if (product.EmployeeName == employee.Name && product.EmployeeLastName == employee.LastName)
            {
                double money = product.Count * product.Price;
                earnings.AddMoney(money);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, certain elements lend themselves to using LINQ.  What exactly are you having a hard time understanding?  Be more specific.

Comment: In what scenario would `EarningsList` contain `earnings` before the `Add` as per your `if` condition?  Is `Earnings` IEquatable on some key?

Comment: Then don´t do this, if it´s too complicated. I assume the LINQ-solution won´t be more readable than your current code.

Comment: Is there any logic in AddMoney ?

Comment: as @HimBromBeere says. Linq would be to complex to read and also debug. Your current solution would be fine.

Comment: In addition, the Q in LINQ stands for **Query**. What you want to do is **modify** items in your collection, which can hardly be done with LINQ.

Comment: @Trevor Yes, the key is employee's LastName and Name.

Comment: @HimBromBeere That's not quite right. The part of his code where he sums up all product's money for a given employee *is* a query.

Comment: Well, I could rewrite it as Linq one-liner like `earnings.Add(ProductList.Sum(item => item.Products.Sum(pr => ...etc...)))`, but that won't make it any faster as far as I know.

Comment: I'm still having trouble with the conditional `EarningsList.Add(earnings);`.  If this conditional doesn't add `earnings` into `EarningsList`, then all the other work is moot as `earnings` gets disposed and the end of the loop.  Unless `AddMoney()` has side effects.

Comment: @noob156 This type of question should be posted on Review stack exchange :)

Comment: Sorry but is your Contains condition working correctly? Unless your Earnings implements [IEquatable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx) this should not work?

Comment: @Freggar: The inner part of the loop calls the `AddMoney` method and we have no idea exactly what that does. A loop that calls methods on objects is *not* just a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part isn't so easy to convert because of the conditional  EarningsList.Add()

But You can rewrite the last 2 rather easily.

Assuming that  `AddMoney()` does just what it says, you can use `Sum()`. Otherwise, omit the Sum() and run a separate foreach  on the list of amounts. That would make it a lot less Linq.

```
var amount = ProductList
   .SelectMany(item => item.Products)
   .Where(product => product.EmployeeName == employee.Name && product.EmployeeLastName == employee.LastName)
   .Sum(product => product.Count * product.Price)
   ;

earnings.AddMoney(amount);
```

Comment: This does assume that `AddMoney` can be called like this. We don't know what that method does and it might be that calling `AddMoney(1)` ten times is not the same as calling `AddMoney(10)`. eg it might store a count of how many things have been added and adding them in one go like this could produce different results.

Comment: @Chris - yes, I asked for that a few minutes ago. I'll put it in the answer aswell.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that you'd asked. :) Its a good answer though anyway, just needs that caveat but hopefully the OP would have been able to recognise that himself anyway.

Comment: 1. `SelectMany` and `Where` can be club together. 2. Your answer assumes that the `amount` has to be summed up, whereas in the question it is just added to collection. So convert `Sum()` to `ToList()` and call the result as `earnings`.

Comment: Alright then. :) And you can use two separate joins to convert the original code into two linq queries.

Comment: AddMoney() just does what you guessed, nothing special.

Comment: @bommelding Thank you for your answer. But shouldn't it be .Select(product => product.Count * product.Price)?

Comment: @bommelding Thanks once again. Too bad I can't upvote your answer because I have less than 15 rep :)

Comment: @PratikGaikwad - I merged the Select and the Sum, but I don't see how SelectMany can take a predicate.

Comment: @noob156 I feel like your original algorithm is not doing what you want, my advice is that you review the original idea a bit. You should normalize your data, try to remove logic from you POCO objects. I am guessing its possible to remove AddMoney completely and just set the Money prop on you object.

Comment: @FilipCordas You're right, my code is kinda bad. I will look it up. Still trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing exactly what the `.AddMoney` method does you could do this:

```
var query =
    from employee in EmployeeList
    let earnings = new Earnings(employee.Name, employee.LastName, employee.Bank, employee.Account)
    from item in ProductList
    from product in item.Products
    where product.EmployeeName == employee.Name
    where product.EmployeeLastName == employee.LastName
    group product.Count * product.Price by earnings;

List<Earnings> EarningsList =
    query
        .Aggregate(new List<Earnings>(), (a, x) =>
        {
            a.Add(x.Key);
            foreach (var y in x)
            {
                x.Key.AddMoney(y);
            }
            return a;
        });
```

If `.AddMoney` simply adds the money arithmetically then you could do this:

```
List<Earnings> EarningsList =
    query
        .Aggregate(new List<Earnings>(), (a, x) =>
        {
            a.Add(x.Key);
            x.Key.AddMoney(x.Sum());
            return a;
        });
```

Just a small note. You're using `double` to represent money. It's best to use `decimal` as this will help prevent rounding errors in your calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want if you just used LINQ(no foreach). This should be compatible with IQueryable as well and you really don't want to do foreach on IQueryable.

```
var newEarnings = from employee in EmployeeList
                              select new Earnings
                              {
                                  Name = employee.Name,
                                  LastName = employee.LastName,
                                  Bank = employee.Bank,
                                  Account = employee.Account,
                                  Money = (from daysData in ProductList
                                           from product in daysData.Products
                                           where employee.Name == product.EmployeeName && employee.LastName == product.EmployeeLastName
                                           select product).Sum(p => p.Count * p.Price)
                              };

            EarningsList = EarningsList.Union(newEarnings).ToList();
```

Now in regards to normalization. My guess is that you made you POCO models like this in order to show it in some sort of a grid. You really should not let your UI dictate what you data models look like. There can be others reasons to do this but they are related to performance and I don't think you need to worry about this just jet. So here is my advice on how to change this.

1. Add Id property to all the classes. This is always a good idea no
   matter what you are doing. This can be a random string or an auto
   increment, just to have a unique value so you can play with this
   object.
2. Add reference properties in you classes. Don't copy the values from
   Employee to Product and Earnings. Just add a Property of type
   Employee and/or add the EmployeeId property

So your POCO should look something like this

```
public class Employee
{
    //It can be a Guid, string or what ever. I am not nesseserly recomending using Guids and you should look into this a bit more   
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Bank { get; set; }

    public string Account { get; set; }
}

public class DaysData
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public double Count { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }
}

public class Earnings
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public double Money { get; set; }
}
```

And the query

```
var newEarnings = from employee in EmployeeList
                          select new Earnings
                          {
                              Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                              EmployeeId = employee.Id,
                              Employee = employee,
                              Money = (from daysData in ProductList
                                       from product in daysData.Products
                                       where employee.Id == product.EmployeeId
                                       select product).Sum(p => p.Count * p.Price)
                          };
```

Once you try to implement data persistence this will help you a lot no matter what you use EF, Mongo, Elsatic, AzureTables or anything else even a simple saving to files.